# Funny Thread Behaviour in Scala

Tags: java, multithreading, scala

I'm making some experiments to try and understand Threads in practice. Please look at the following snippet: It's a `main` function that spawns a thread listening on port 2020. This thread, in turn, listens for connections on this port and, whenever a client connects, it spawns *another* thread that sleeps a little bit and then writes to the socket.

```
class MyRunner(s:Socket,num:Int) extends Runnable{

  val r = scala.util.Random

  def run(): Unit ={

    if(num == 5 )
      Thread.sleep(15000)
    else
      Thread.sleep(1000)

    s.getOutputStream.write(s"My number is  ${num}!  \n".getBytes)
    s.getOutputStream.close()
  }
}

// this thread opens a MyRunner thread on each new connection
class MyService extends Runnable{

  val serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2020)

  var num = 0

  def run():Unit = {
    while(true){
      val socket = serverSocket.accept()
      num += 1
      (new MyRunner(socket,num)).run()
    }
  }
}

// main function
object app {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    (new MyService).run
  }
}
```

Now I'm testing this setup. Here's what I did: I opened two terminal windows and, on each of them I entered the command:

```
$ for i in `seq 1 5`; do netcat localhost 2020; done
```

Thing is, when number 5 is reached (as per the conditional) on one of the terminals, the other one does not continue running. Both clients stop until the 15-second timeout is finished.

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong because I thought the whole purpose of using threads was to have nonblocking apps that can serve a client even though the other is busy.

P.S.: I'm running this on a VirtualBox VM with 4 available processors (from the total 8 in my host machine).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your app does not create any threads.  Create a thread like this:

```
Thread serverThread = new Thread(new MyService());
serverThread.start();
```

The `thread.start()` method is the low-level method that is provided by the library for your code to call when you want to create a new thread.

The `serverThread.run()` method is the method that *your code* provides for the *library* to call *in* the new thread.

---

Extra Credit:  Learn how to use a thread pool (e.g., `java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor`) instead of creating and destroying a new thread for every client connection.  Creating and destroying threads is expensive.

Comment: Yeah. I knew I had misunderstood something. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any good source where learn about ThreadPoolExcecutor?

Comment: @Shondeslitch, the "concurrency" chapter in the standard Java tutorial probably is a good place to start:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html